Twin Paradox problem
I'm working on special relativity and I need to solve the problem of the twin brothers.
The problem states that the astronaut twin takes off at the age of 21 moves in a straight line away from earth to a star X at $v = \frac{4}{5}c$, at the star X he makes an instantaneous U-turn and comes back to earth at the age of 39.
The book that I'm working with says that to solve the problem we need three reference frames, we have $\mathcal{O}$ which is the RF on the Earth, $\mathcal{O}'$ the RF on the starship on the way to the star and $\mathcal{O}''$ the RF on the starship returning from the star. And it assumes that at the start $ t=t'=t''=0 $ and the origins of the reference frames coincide.
It asks me: Considering the event $p$ represented by the u-turn that the starship makes near the star, find the coordinates of $p$ in $\mathcal{O}$, $\mathcal{O}'$ and $\mathcal{O}''$.
I know that for the astronaut $\Delta\tau = 18\;\text{yrs}$, so that means that for $\mathcal{O}$ we have $ \Delta t=\gamma_{v}\Delta\tau=30\;\text{yrs}$ and the distance the star is from the Earth is given from $d=v\frac{\Delta t}{2} = 12\;\text{lyrs}$.
So I have that for $\mathcal{O}$:
$$ t=15\;\text{yrs}, \quad x = 12\;\text{lyrs} $$
To find the coordinates of the event in $\mathcal{O}'$ and $\mathcal{O}''$ I apply the Lorentz transformation for a boost on the $x$-axis and I get for $\mathcal{O}'$ assuming $\beta = \frac{4}{5}$:
$$ t' = 9\;\text{yrs}, \quad x' = 0\,\text{lyrs} $$
And for $\mathcal{O}''$ assuming $ \beta = -\frac{4}{5}$:
$$ t''=41\;\text{yrs}, \quad x'' = 40\,\text{lyrs} $$
The problem I have is understanding why these are the results for $\mathcal{O}''$, I can't comprehend how does $\mathcal{O}''$ move for $t>0$ assuming that all three reference frames coincide at $t=0$.

I hope this does not get closed as homework. You are asking a conceptual question, but it is at the very end of a homework description.

I wouldn't say that the frames coincide at $t=0$. I would say that they all share the same origin, meaning that the same event has the coordinates $(t_0=t'_0=t''_0=0,x_0=x'_0=x''_0=0)$.
$O''$ simply moves to the left with respect to $O$, just as $O'$ moves to the right with respect to $O$. There is nothing fancy or different about $O''$. If I may guess about the likely source of your confusion, you may view an inertial frame as being attached to the origin or as being a physical object or having some sort of limited extent. An inertial frame (in SR) extends throughout all space and all time. It covers all events and assigns all events everywhere some specified coordinates. $O''$ simply moves to the left relative to $O$ at all times, so it assigns a large positive number to the position of event $p$.
